# How to query a table for different columns based on first column result

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Is there a way to, in a single query, return rows of `my_table where column_1 = "xxx"` if it does have results, and if it doesnt, return `where column_2 = "xxx"` ?

Like a `select * from my_table where column_1 = "xxx" or column_2 = "xxx"`
but only displaying the `column_2= "xxx"` if there is no results for `column_1 = "xxx"`

This table has 400M+ rows, so please take performance into account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
  from my_table 
 where (column_1 = "xxx"
   and exists (select null from my_table where column_1 = "xxx"))
    or (column_2 = "xxx"
   and not exists (select null from my_table where column_1 = "xxx"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where column_1 = 'xxx'
union all
select t.*
from my_table t
where column_2 = 'xxx' and 
      not exists (select 1 from my_table where column_1 = 'xxx');
```

This should have reasonable performance if you have an index on `column_1` and another index on `column_2`.

If you are only expecting one value, you can do something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from my_table t
      where column_1 = 'xxx' or column_2 = 'xxx'
      order by (case when column_1 = 'xxx' then 1 else 2 end)
     ) t
where rownum = 1;
```

This will not make use of an index (at least not very well), but it will accomplish what you want with a single scan of the table.

Answer (score 0):

depending on my interpretation of your question:

```
select decode( column1,'xxx',column1,column2 )
from my_table
where column1 = 'xxx' or column2 = 'xxx'
```